# How can I increase height of navbar after hamburger toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I included a working example of my code, and here is my problem. I made my own hamburger menu icon and used `@media` and `overflow: none` to place my nav items under the navbar, hidden from view when a viewport of 900px or less is achieved.

My goal is to increase the height of the navbar to reveal nav items once the hamburger has been toggled. What is the best logic/ formatting I can use to achieve this?

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!menuOpen) {
        menuBtn.classList.add('open');
        menuOpen = true;
    } else {
        menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
        menuOpen = false;
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav.nav {
  background: black;
  max-height: 30vh;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .brand a {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0rem;
  align-items: center;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .nav-list .nav-item {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .social-media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 8rem;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .social-media .icons i {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 80%;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn .menu-btn-burger {
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn .menu-btn-burger::before,
nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn .menu-btn-burger::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn .menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn .menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

/* Hamburger animation */

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

nav.nav .nav-bar .hamburger .menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

.collapse {
  height: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
        <div class="nav-bar flex-row">
            <div class="brand">
                <a href="index.html">David Anthony</a>
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <div class="menu-btn">
                        <div class="menu-btn-burger"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="social-media">
                <div class="icons">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            

            
            
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Why does the navbar need to get taller to show menu options?  `position: fixed; top: 25px; right: 0` or some numbers and just make the submenu show where it should

Comment: Nav items show as in a traditional navigation bar once the screen is larger than 900px. As the screen gets smaller, the items get bunched together and so, once screen gets smaller than 900px, I switched the flex-direction to column and hide them from view until the user wants to access them via hamburger. Please let me know If I've understood your question.